# CAS SSO Docker Image fails caused by Tomcat Server

Tags: docker, tomcat, cas

When I'm trying to run my docker image. It seems there's something missing, but I can't figure it out yet.

Exception is triggered by:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat server
```

You can see images posted below

Any ideas?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wjuv5.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKpnK.png)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIDI6.png)

Comment: Always specify the CAS version in your question. Also, instead of attaching images of the logs, attach the logs and relevant error messages as text.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation provided on the README](https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template):

> Create a keystore file thekeystore under /etc/cas. Use the password changeit for both the keystore and the key/certificate entries. This can either be done using the JDK's keytool utility or via the following command:
>   `./gradlew[.bat] createKeystore`
>   Ensure the keystore is loaded up with keys and certificates of the server.

Comment: I followed the readme file but still fails.

After run
 # Use --refresh-dependencies to force-update SNAPSHOT versions
./gradlew[.bat] clean build

I get the following error:

`Could not find com.google.cloud.tools:jib-gradle-plugin:2.3.0.`

Comment: I'd like to know which version do you recommend to install and run CAS. Could you provide me a link?

Comment: Recommendations are usually based on this policy: https://apereo.github.io/cas/developer/Maintenance-Policy.html Also read https://apereo.github.io/2017/03/08/the-myth-of-ga-rel/